# What innate spellcasting abilities can the Spell Thief steal?

Tags: dnd-5e

This question is on the [Spell Thief](http://mfov.magehandpress.com/2016/03/spellthief.html), a homebrew class presented by [Middle Finger of Vecna](http://mfov.magehandpress.com), and its ability to steal spells.

When the ability says "innate spellcasting feature" this means things like Dragons breath attacks and Beholders ray attacks right or a spell via Magic Initiate feat right? If so and then take for example the Spell Thief stole a Dragon's Breath attack, does it mean the dragon has a to roll to recharge its breath attack right before it can use it again thus literally robbing it of its use temporarily?

Comment: In the Homebrew section of MFV is where the Spell Thief is at in the Rogues' section/gui/icon/thingy.  Sorry for the confusion. MFV is just the name of the group making the Homebrew material. I guess it's an inside joke for them or somethign.

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it clear that you are not referencing the 17th level Arcane Trickster ability, and instead are talking about third party material

Comment: It appears that you have two related questions. I would suggest editing them and this one so that the question is clear in the title, to help other users who are searching for answers. "Question about X, part 2" doesn't mean much to a search engine.

Answer (score 4):

No. This means exactly what it says. Many monsters have a feature called Innate Spellcasting. For example, the Storm Giant has:

> ***Innate
>   Spellcasting.***
>   The
>   giant’s
>   innate
>   spellcasting
>   ability
>   is
>   Charisma
>   (spell
>   save
>   DC
>   17).
>   It
>   can
>   innately
>   cast
>   the
>   following
>   spells,
>   requiring
>   no
>   material
>   components: